# Warum "-en" in "Einparteienstaat" oder "Einparteiensystem"?

Tags: etymology

Ich frage mich, warum zum Teil der Wörter [Einparteienstaat](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einparteienstaat?title=Einparteienstaat&redirect=no) und [Einparteiensystem](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einparteiensystem) das `-en` gehört, obwohl sich dabei um nur eine Partei handelt. Gibt es andere ähnliche Beispiele?

Comment: Gute Frage... Ein anderes Beispiel wäre [Einphasen-Wechselrichter](http://www.energie-experten.org/erneuerbare-energien/photovoltaik/wechselrichter/phasenwechselrichter.html). Vielleicht erfahren wir aus den Antworten auch gleich, warum es andererseits heißt "Zwei-Raum-Wohnung" und "Vier-Kern-Prozessor".

Comment: Aus *Einparteienstaat* und *Einparteiensystem* lassen sich *Zweiparteien-*, *Dreiparteien-*, *Mehrparteien-*, etc. formen. Evtl. hilft das?

Comment: Ein paar weitere Beispiele: *Einkindpolitik, Annenstift, Einpersonenhaushalt.*

Comment: Es könnte auch am Geschlecht liegen, aber dazu müsste man sich mehr Beispiele ansehen. Jedenfalls ist Eine-Partei-Staat durch das „eine“ sperrig.

Comment: Orangensaft vs. Apfelsaft (nicht: Äpfelsäft).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Der erste Teil eines Kompositums kann im Deutschen **morphologisch** in diverse Fälle und Numeri gesetzt werden, ohne dass dies eine **inhaltliche** Auswirkung zu haben braucht. Es gibt keine einheitlichen Regeln, was gewählt wird. Das Wichtigste scheint mir zu sein, dass sich das Resultat flüssig aussprechen lässt, aber auch das gilt nicht immer.

Ein paar Beispiele:

> Apfelernte
>   Birnenernte
>   Hirseernte
>   Gerstenernte
>
> Mondbahn
>   Erdbahn
>   Sonnenbahn
>   Kometenbahn
>
> Peterkirche
>   Petersdom
>   Lutherkirche
>   Marienkirche

Siehe auch [Wikipedia hierzu](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut).

Comment: Gelegentlich wird das -en- auch in der Poesie und Literatur verwendet. Man denke z.b. an "Mondenkind" aus der unendlichen Geschichte.

Answer (score 1):

Da die Beispiele bereits in Kommentaren genannt wurden versuche ich mich nun an einer Erklärung:

Während bei den Wörtern *Kern* und *Raum* der Plural jeweils ein `e` am Ende hat: *Kerne*, *Räume* - haben der Plural von *Partei* und auch *Person* ein `en` am Ende:
*Parteien*, *Personen*.

Comment: Ich kontere mit "Vorderachsantrieb" ;)