# Why is it "Zwei-Mann-Orchester" instead of "Zwei-Männer-Orchester"?

Tags: grammatical-number

In the [repertoire of the "Musiktheater im Revier"](http://www.musiktheater-im-revier.de/Spielplan/Oper/Overview/2014-15/ZweiMannOrchester/) I found the compound word

> Zwei-Mann-Orchester

I wonder why it is "Mann" here. When they're two, shouldn't it be plural "Zwei Männer"?

Comment: This is not specific to German. In English it would be the same, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Matt L.: True, _two-piece_ (or _two-man_) _orchestra_. Also _two-bedroom flat_ (_Dreizimmerwohnung_, where singular and plural are indistinguishable, but also _Dreiraumwohnung_ in some regions).

Comment: @MattL. But _Zwei-Personen-Haushalt_ and _Zweiparteiensystem_ use the plural (even if you replace _zwei_ by _ein_!), while their English counterparts don't. The English rule about how to handle this might be related, which is no surprise for two languages that are so close, but this question _is_ specific to German.

Comment: Related: [Warum “-en” in “Einparteienstaat” oder “Einparteiensystem”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/17676/2594).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Das Wort *Mann* wird hier als [Zählwort](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C3%A4hlwort) gebraucht, also als eine Art Maßeinheit im Sinne von "dieses Orchester hat eine Größe von zwei Mann". Andere Beispiele im Deutschen sind u.a. *Bund*, *Stück*, *Paar* und *Schuss*.

> Kauf noch zwei Bund Petersilie und vier Stück Butter.
>   In den Urlaub nehme ich 3 Paar Schuhe mit.
>   An die Soldaten wurden 1000 Schuss Munition ausgegeben.
>   Dieses Schiff hat 10 Mann Besatzung.

Übrigens: das Wort *Mann* hat ohnehin schon zwei Pluralformen - neben der neueren Form *Männer* gibt es noch das alte *Mannen*, das heute nur noch in bestimmten Kontexten ("Lehns- und Gefolgsleute (und ähnliche Gruppen)" schreibt [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mann)) verwendet wird. Wenn man, wie es Wiktionary und auch der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mann_Person_Gatte_Anrede) in ihrer Darstellung suggerieren, das Zählwort *Mann* auch als eine besondere Pluralform von *Mann* auffasst, so kann man sagen, dass "Mann" drei Pluralformen hat. Ich wüsste auf die Schnelle kein weiteres Wort mit dieser Eigenschaft.

> In der Halbzeitpause scharte der Trainer seine *Mannen* um sich und sprach: "*Männer*, es mag Euch zwar vorkommen, als habe der Gegner heute 12 *Mann* auf dem Platz. Aber Ihr geht jetzt raus und haut sie trotzdem weg!"

;-)

Comment: Superbeispiel da unten! +11