# Was ist die Präposition à?

Tags: preposition

Die folgende Beschreibung einer Packung von Küchentüchern [von Rossmann](https://web.archive.org/web/20150504144713/http://www.rossmannversand.de:80/produkt/4179/alouette-kuechentuecher.aspx)

> „4 Rollen à 51 Blatt = 204 Blatt“

motiviert diese Frage. Wieso steht das Nomen nach **à** im Singular? Laut canoo.net soll  [à](http://canoonet.eu/%C3%A0?lookup=caseSensitive) eine Präposition mit Akkusativ sein, also *Blatt* anstelle *Blätter* kann ich nicht erklären.

Comment: Siehe die (deutschsprachige) Antwort zu http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23833/why-is-it-zwei-mann-orchester-instead-of-zwei-m%C3%A4nner-orchester Mit *à* speziell hat es nichts zu tun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das mit dem Akkusativ, der von *à* verlangt wird, stimmt zwar, aber die nicht deklinierte Verwendung von *Blatt* hat speziell mit *à* nichts zu tun.

Hier wird *Blatt* nämlich als Maßeinheit verwendet und aus diesem Grund nicht dekliniert.

Detaillierter kann man das hier nachlesen: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/23834/1487