# "Sieben Mann" statt "Sieben Männer"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar-identification, grammatical-number

Im Buch "Wo warst du, Adam?" von H. Böll habe ich den folgenden Satz gefunden:

"Die sieben Mann vom Nachkommando saßen dort, wo die Küche gewesen war".

Warum kann man "sieben Mann" statt "sieben Männer" sagen? Man kann schon sehen, dass das Verb im Plural ist ("saßen"), und ich verstehe nicht, warum das Substantiv im Singular ist.
Ich habe dieses Konstrukt schon in andere Bücher gefunden (es scheint mir, es ist sehr üblich in der Literatur), aber ich habe bisher keine richtige Antwort gefunden.

Danke im Voraus für die Erklärungen.

Edit: ich habe nach änliche Fragen gesucht, aber die einzige, die ich gefunden habe ist diese ([Why is it "Zwei-Mann-Orchester" instead of "Zwei-Männer-Orchester"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23833/why-is-it-zwei-mann-orchester-instead-of-zwei-m%c3%a4nner-orchester)), die leider nicht meine Frage geantwortet.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. D.h., die gefundene Frage samt Antwort erklärt nicht, dass "sieben Mann" hier analog wie drüben eine Zähleinheit ist? Weil die Beispiele dort zur Maßeinheit dann keinen Plural im Verb verwenden?

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Mann#d-1-3-3

Comment: @Shegit Brahm: genau, das ist das Problem. Ich verstehe, dass ich "Ich habe ein Zwei-Mann Betrieb gegründet" sagen kann, dort ist es fast ein Adjektiv. Aber mit dem Verb habe ich Schwierigkeiten

Comment: @Eugen: Dann bitte den Unterschied zur anderen Frage etwas deutlicher herausstellen. Das Problem mit dem Singular wird im Fragetext thematisiert, warum jetzt die andere Frage noch Fragen offen lässt, irgendwie nicht so ganz, meine ich.

Comment: The Usage note in the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mann#German) seems relevant. (The German Wiktionary only mentions the dated *Mannen* btw.) English sometimes uses 'man' when referring to more than one person, e.g. a "twelve man squad"; that's clearly not the case here though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Das ist kein Singular, sondern die zweite Pluralform von *Mann*.

Es gibt eine Reihe von Wörtern, die zwei verschiedene Pluralformen haben. Ein paar Beispiele:

- **das Wort**

  - **die Wörter**
    wenn sie bloß eine Anhäufung ohne inneren Zusammenhang sind. (*»Wörterbuch«*)
  - **die Worte**
    wenn sie in einem sinntragenden Zusammenhang stehen. (*»Er sprach weise Worte.«*)
- **das Land**

  - **die Länder**
    wenn zwischen ihnen kein besonderer Zusammenhang besteht
  - **die Lande**
    wenn sie irgendwie zusammengehören (*»Er zog durch die Lande.«*)
- **das Tuch**

  - **die Tücher**
    wenn zwischen ihnen kein besonderer Zusammenhang besteht
  - **die Tuche**
    wenn sie der Tuchhändler gemeinsam von der Rolle verkauft

Und beim Mann ist es genau so:

- **der Mann**

  - **die Männer**
    wenn zwischen ihnen kein besonderer Zusammenhang besteht
  - **die Mann, die Mannen**
    wenn sie zusammen gehören (*»Mannschaft«* statt *»Männerschaft«, »alle Mann an Bord«, »die Mannen des Dietrich von Bern«*

---

Bei den oben genannten Wörtern ist die Form, die auf *-er* endet, die zusammenhanglose. Beim ***Ding*** ist es genau umgekehrt. Wenn zwei ***Dinge*** zu erledigen sind, haben sie für gewöhnlich nichts miteinander zu tun. Die dicken ***Dinger*** einer vollbusigen Frau gehören aber zusammen.

---

### Nachtrag: Belege

In einem Kommentar wurde ein Beleg dafür verlangt, dass *die Mann* tatsächlich eine valide Pluralform von *der Mann* ist. Weil ich fürchte, das diese Belege in den Kommentaren untergehen, füge ich hier ein paar ein:

- Buch: [Zwei Mann auf Pilgerfahrt](http://jungundjung.at/content.php?id=2&b_id=292)
- Film: [Drei Mann in einem Boot](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drei_Mann_in_einem_Boot_(1961))
- Kinderbuch: [Vier Mann auf Trimarana](https://shop.falter.at/detail/9783962291198)
- Buch: [Fünf Mann Ein Brot](https://lib.ugent.be/catalog/rug01:001287714)
- Fernsehserie: [Ein Mädchen und sechs Mann](https://www.fernsehserien.de/ein-maedchen-und-sechs-mann)
- Film: [Sieben Mann und ein Luder](https://www.mdr.de/tv/programm/sendung875406.html)
- Spielfilm: [Acht Mann und ein Skandal](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acht_Mann_und_ein_Skandal)
- Zeitungsartikel: [Neun Mann und eine Meinung](https://www.zeit.de/1970/04/neun-mann-und-eine-meinung)
- anderer Zeitungsartikel: [Sieg mit zehn Mann](https://www.ligaportal.at/international/deutsche-bundesliga/28452-sieg-mit-zehn-mann-paderborn-gibt-sich-nicht-auf)
- Artikel in einem Magazin: [Elf Mann über Bord](https://www.yacht.de/aktuell/panorama/elf-mann-ueber-bord/a125442.html)
- Buch: [Zwölf Mann und ein Kapitän.](https://www.zvab.com/erstausgabe/Zw%C3%B6lf-Mann-Kapit%C3%A4n-Novellen-Plivier-Theodor/30238259410/bd)
- Film: [Dreizehn Mann und eine Kanone](https://www.murnau-stiftung.de/movie/144)
- Zeitungsartikel: [Vierzehn Mann an einem Tisch](https://www.mz-web.de/bitterfeld/evakuierung-vierzehn-mann-an-einem-tisch-9677444)
- Piratenlied: [15 Mann auf des toten Manns Kiste](http://www.klabautern.de/2016/02/15-mann-auf-des-toten-manns-kiste-lied/)

Und wer gerne eine Deklinationstabelle hat: In der Spalte "Mengen" steht die gesuchte Pluralform in allen vier Fällen: [Deklination und Plural von Mann](https://www.verbformen.de/deklination/substantive/Mann.htm)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143103/discussion-on-answer-by-hubert-scholnast-sieben-mann-statt-sieben-manner); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Die Frage, was der Zweck von Kommentaren auf dieser Website ist, ist hinreichend diskutiert. Falls du zu dieser Diskussion etwas Neues hinzufügen willst, tu das bitte auf Meta. Du musst die Regeln nicht gut finden, aber du wirst sie akzeptieren müssen.

Answer (score 3):

Die Regel ist, dass bei maskulinen und neutralen Maßbezeichnungen die Singularform unabhängig vom Numerus des Rests der Nominalphrase steht.

> Er hat schon wieder ein oder zwei Pfund Kirschen gegessen.
> ein Schiff mit ein oder zwei Mann Besatzung

Wenn es sich nicht um eine Maßbezeichnung handelt, kann *Mann* nicht das Merkmal Plural haben.

> Das sind zwei nette Männer/*Mann.

Da die Verwendung allgemeinen Regeln folgt, gibt es keinen Grund, Pluralformen wie *Pfund, Mann* auf einer lexikalischen Ebene anzunehmen. Das würde auch das deutsche Pluralsystem durcheinanderbringen, in dem strukturell nur Nomen auf *-er, -en, -el* Nullplural haben.

In der Duden-Grammatik, 9. Auflage, heißt es dazu unter Randnummer 270:

> (ii) Maß- und Mengenbezeichnungen mit Genus Maskulinum und Neutrum weisen
> gewöhnlich die Singularform auf, auch wenn sie pluralisch zu verstehen sind (Unterlassung
> der Pluralflexion), und zwar unabhängig davon, ob das Gemessene folgt
> (a) oder nicht (b).

Comment: So weit, so überzeugend. Interessant wäre nun allerdings, wie sich dazu der Ausdruck [alle Mann](https://www.dwds.de/wb/alle%20Mann) (an Bord, an Deck, in Deckung) verhält, der offenbar auch Flexionen wie »Der Bauhof ist mit *allen Mann* mit den Reinigungsarbeiten beschäftigt« (zit. nach DWDS, a.a.O.) zulässt.

Comment: Wegen der Auslassung des Gemessenen? Oder weil man es nicht als Maßangabe auffaßt? Man könnte es als Wendung sehen. Aber den Nullplural aus dem Mhd. halte ich für ausgestorben. [DWB](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=M00930) hat da z.B. den Beleg: *die weiber haben eben ein kleidung wie die mann.*

Comment: Tatsächlich bereitet mir in diesem Fall die Auffassung als Maßangabe im Singular einige Schwierigkeiten, da mir analoge Ausdrücke wie (ausgehend von *mit zwei Glas Wasser*) _mit allen Glas Wasser_ oder gar _mit allen Glas_ recht ungewöhnlich vorkommen. Deutlich üblicher dürfte hier der Plural *mit allen Gläsern [Wasser]* sein. Daher wäre ich intuitiv davon ausgegangen, dass *Mann* in der Phrase *mit allen Mann* doch das Merkmal Plural hat (möglicherweise als mhd. Relikt).