# No umlaut in some plural nouns

Tags: noun, grammatical-number, umlaut

Some masculine and neuter nouns don’t umlaut the last vowel in the stem of the word in the plural when it would be possible. What’s the historical reason for this?

Comment: Welcome. No idea what you mean. Do you have an example ?

Comment: *Tor* is neutrum, *Tore* its plural, while it could theoretically support a diaeresis. Do you want the historical reason for this instead of (say) *Töre*?

Comment: Yes. Also words like Schuh, Ort, and Hund.  In other words, why don’t all words have the last a, o, or u umlauted in the plural?

Comment: @Timoig: Ort has both plural forms, with slightly different meanings: Orte and Örter

Answer (score 3):

In present-day German, masculine nouns with the plural suffix *‑e* fall into two different declension classes, depending on whether they have umlaut or not. That is, for these nouns, umlaut is not predictable and must be learned.

> suffix *‑e* and umlaut: *Baum – Bäume, Fuß – Füße, Gast – Gäste, Stock – Stöcke, …*
>
> suffix *‑e* and no umlaut: *Arm – Arme, Laut – Laute, Mord – Morde, Schuh – Schuhe, …*

There is no single historical reason for nouns belonging to either class. For instance, although the umlaut of *Gäste* can be traced back to Old High German pairs such as *gast – gesti* (with umlaut triggered by the suffix *‑i*), the same cannot be said for *Bäume* (OHG *boum – bouma*).

In the course of history, there has been a lot of variation with regard to how a given noun forms its plural. Remainders of these processes are still visible in words that have multiple ways to form the plural. For instance, both *die Wagen* and *die Wägen* is accepted.

Masculine nouns with no suffix in the plural behave similarly to those with *‑e* treated above: umlaut is not predictable.

> no suffix and umlaut: *Graben – Gräben, Mangel – Mängel, Vater – Väter, …*
>
> no suffix and no umlaut (sg. = pl.): *Kabel, Maler, Schatten, …*

In all other instances, umlaut is predictable.

- Neuter nouns belonging to either of the two classes above (suffix *‑e* in the plural or no suffix in the plural) do not have umlaut. There are a few famous counterexamples, but these are very much the exception that proves the rule.
- Feminine nouns belonging to either of the two classes above always have umlaut (where possible).
- For all other plural classes, umlaut is predictable: *‑er* always has umlaut (where possible), *‑n* and *‑s* never have it.

Comment: Is there somewhere that I can see which nouns belong to which class? For strong verbs, for instance, there are places where I can see them broken down into classes I through VII

Comment: So an umlauted vowel hasn’t been generalized to be a morpheme for plurality in nouns?

Comment: @Timoig There are nouns (specifically, the class with zero plural and no umlaut) where umlaut is the only marker of plural number: *Graben ‑ Gräben, Mangel ‑ Mängel*. In all other instances, umlaut is a pleonastic marker of plural. How the plural is formed is listed in dictionaries, although I know of no dictionary that would allow one to get, for instance, a list of all masculine nouns with *e*-plural and no umlaut.

Comment: *Zero plural and no umlaut*: strike the *no*.

Comment: The plural umlaut is mostly a carry over from German's ancient roots. The words that require one tend be those a medieval peasant might use. For example, they occur with almost all plurals of close relatives (*Brüder, Väter, Mütter*). This probably isn't that valuable as a rule though, since it probably does only marginally better than random guessing.

Comment: There's also words with two different plurals: Wort - Worte / Wörter where the two different plural have slightly different meaning. And words where the Umlaut only shows in the deminuitive: Bohne - Bohnen (but Böhnchen as diminuitive)

Comment: @Timoig: It seems to me as if you were trying to find a structure or general rule where there is none. Some (many, actually) things just must be learned, as tedious as it may seem :-)

Comment: @DavidVogt Ort has both plural forms: Orte and Örter. E.g. see https://www.wortbedeutung.info/%C3%96rter/

Comment: @planetmaker I understand OP's question to be about the predictability of umlaut in the plural, not about the predictability of what plural suffix occurs.

Comment: @DavidVogt I totally agree. And there is little rule other than 'you have to memorize the declension for each word' (which you explain well).

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific reason. Some people just preferred one of both versions and other people have copied them, and so one form became more frequently used and the other became extinct.

This happened to the majority of all nouns. But there are still some nouns that have two different plural forms, often with different meanings:

- der Mann

  - die Mannen; die Mann (alle Mann an Bord)
    (see also [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/60627/1487))
  - die Männer
- das Land

  - die Lande (durch die Lande ziehen)
  - die Länder
- das Wort

  - die Worte
  - die Wörter
- das Wasser

  - die Wasser (mit allen Wassern gewaschen)
  - die Wässer
- der Mund

  - die Munde (in aller Munde sein)
  - die Münder
- der General

  - die Generale
  - die Generäle (mainly in Austria)
- das Tuch

  - die Tuche (drapery, fabrics)
  - die Tücher (cloths, scarfs, ...)

Comment: Bleibt anzumerken daß es schon lange nicht mehr "Mann" sondern "Mensch" heißt nautisch (englisch: "person"). Und der Plural von "der Schild" ist "die Schilde", nicht "die Schilder", die sind der Plural von "das Schild" (siehe dwds). Auch dann nicht, wenn auf dem Schild was draufsteht ...

Comment: @a_donda: 1. »Menschen an Bord« und »Mann an Bord« werden seit rund 10 Jahren annähernd gleich häufig benutzt, davor war »Mann an Bord« deutlich häufiger. Zu keiner Zeit wurde »Menschen an Bord« signifikant häufiger verwendet als »Mann an Bord«. Siehe  [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Mann+an+Bord%2CMenschen+an+Bord&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3) 2. Wieso Schild? Das steht da nirgends.

Comment: Ich habe einen englischen yachtmaster ocean und einen deutschen Hochseeschifferschein und es heißt "Mensch" und "person", egal was google sagt. In der Zählung sind ja auch Leute wie hier drin oder Wikipedia-Artikel, die die Begriffe falsch verwenden. "Mann" und "man" sind beide veraltet wegen Geschlechterangleichung. Schild ist in deiner verlinkten Antwort, wo der den Plural falsch beschrieben hast. Generell würden deine Antworten besser durch Quellenangaben, die regelmäßig fehlen.

Comment: @a_donda: Du kritisierst in ein und demselben Kommentar, dass ich eine Quelle angebe (nämlich das N-Gramm) und forderst zugleich, dass ich mehr Quellenangaben machen soll. Was denn nun? Davon abgesehen: Was richtig und was falsch ist, bestimmen keine Quellen, sondern das bestimmt die Mehrheit der Muttersprachler. Die hochgelobten Quellen schauen auch nur den Muttersprachlern auf's Maul. Und du wirst leider einsehen müssen, dass deine Marineausbildung leider keinen Einfluss darauf, wie knapp 100 Millionen Menschen (die mehrheitlich keine Seeleute sind) ihre Muttersprache verwenden.

Comment: @a_donda: Du hast natürlich recht, dass Quellenangaben häufig sinnvoll sind. Aber Antworten auf German.stackexchange sind keine wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten, und Stackexchange hat sich auch nicht zum Ziel gesetzt, ein Wiki zu sein. In den Regeln von Stackexchange wird nirgendwo verlangt, dass man seine Antworten mit Quellen belegen soll.

Comment: @a_donda: Hier geht es nicht um eine Fachsprache, sondern um allgemeines Deutsch. Es mag schon sein, dass "alle Mann an Bord" unter Seeleuten neuerdings als falsch gilt, aber so leid es mir tut: Das tut hier nichts zur Sache. Die Google N-Gramme sind etwas anderes als die Ergebnisse der Google-Suche. Bei den N-Grammen werden eingescannte Bücher ausgewertet, nicht das Internet. Und es ist nun mal so, dass kein anderes Unternehmen und keine andere Universität auch nur annähernd so viele Bücher eingescannt hat wie Google. ...

Comment: ... Daher sind derzeit die N-Gramme von Google die verlässlichste Quelle wenn es um Häufigkeiten von Wörtern und Phrasen in gedruckten Texten geht.

Comment: Es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen Antwort googeln und Antwort kennen. "Mensch über Bord" und "Person overboard" sind seemännsiche Begriffe. Quellenangaben würden eine Antwort nachvollziehbarer machen und persönliche Meinungen abgrenzen. Sie würden auch einer Verdummung im Internet durch die Verwendung ewig gleicher Links entgegenwirken, das verstärkt nur die Zähler von Seiten wie Google und wird zum Selbstläufer von Mißinformation (nicht persönlich gemeint, nur eine allgemeine Tatsache !). Google ist generell keine verläßlich Quelle. Es bleibt noch der Fehler mit dem Plural des Schildes.

Comment: @a_donda: Wenn du einen Kommentar, auf den ich bereits um 8:19 Uhr geantwortet habe, löscht und um 8:30 Uhr erneut einfügst, erscheint die neu eingefügte Version unter meiner Antwort. Das ist für jeden, der die Kommentare hier liest, sehr verwirrend. Bitte unterlasse es, deine Kommentare auf diese Weise nachträglich zu manipulieren. Du hast immer genau 5 Minuten Zeit um Kommentare zu editieren, danach ist es vorbei.